# Scaling and translating a mesh to match another

Tags: meshlab

Is there a way to take 1 mesh and scale and translate it to match another meshes size and reference/coordinate system, and then export only the changed mesh (not the reference mesh or a merged/combined mesh) with the scale and translation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Alignment functionality. Look at the Mr P tutorials for an introduction

https://www.youtube.com/user/MrPMeshLabTutorials/search?query=align